# Jupyter lab environment

Tags: python, environment, jupyter-lab

I installed python 3 in "base" environment inside Anaconda. However, when I start the new terminal inside JupyterLab, the python is 2.7 even though the environment "(base)" showing on the prompt. I cannot figure out how to make the (base) to run python 3 in the terminal. Please help and many thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53082441/set-my-jupyter-notebook-to-use-python-version-of-an-enviroment. Hope this helps

Comment: As an aside, **don't use the base environment**. Make a separate environment for each project. _I installed python 3 in "base" environment inside Anaconda._ Isn't Python 3 already in base by default, anyway?